# Call wordpress sidebar via functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I'm just curious - is there any way to call a sidebar inside function? lets say we have a sidebar called sidebar-A. I'm registering it in that way:

```
function custom_sidebars() {

     register_sidebar( array(
        'id'            => 'sidebar-a',
        'class'         => 'sidebar-a',
        'name'          => __( 'sidebar-a', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'   => __( 'sidebar-a', 'text_domain' ),
        'before_title'  => '',
        'after_title'   => '',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget'  => '',
    ) );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'custom_sidebars' );
```

and I have an action (which is responsible for displaying specific piece of code in my theme:

```
function bookshop_utils() { 
echo "some text";
echo "some text2";
dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-a');
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_bookshop_utilities', 'bookshop_utils' );
```

but as you think - typing such code (dynamic_sidebar) inside functions is not working. Any ideas how to make it working?

Comment: Do you have any widgets in your sidebar currently?

Comment: And the two echoes in `bookshop_utils` can be seen?

Comment: well it's a regular html so first echo: <div class="notice">Check the price</div> second: <div class="price-range">pick proper price range</div>

Comment: Are you seeing `some text` and `some text2` being outputted?

Comment: well yes. The only issue is with calling the sidebar.

Comment: Do you have a link to the project so I can see the frontend html?

Comment: nope, currently only on localhost.